# Apply conditional formatting to a cell and the one on its immediate left

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

I am making a spreadsheet which categorises examination questions based on topic, type etc. and I would like to know how I can apply conditional formatting both to a cell and to the one immediately to the left of it. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/48twavL.png]

I want a colour scale rule for the `Module` which goes from light to dark, but have this also applied to the `Topic` cell to the left. Alternatively how would I be able to do it for each module/colour combination without gradient scale?

For instance, all module `1.2` questions would be green, say, and the cells to the left of them would also be green.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ideally I'm looking for some kind of formula to put into the 'conditional formatting by formula' bit of Excel.

Comment: You can create a new rule for each module/color combination that will work as you've described but the gradient color scales do not work that way.

Comment: Oh ok, how would I be able to do it for each module/colour combination?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Module` is in D4, select C5:D12 (more rows if you want), HOME > Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, under *Format values where this formula is true:* enter:

```
=$D5=1.2
```

Format..., select green, OK, OK. Repeat as necessary by adding new rules with different colours and adjusting each time `1.2` from the formula above to suit.

To adjust the range to which the CF is applied either use HOME > Clipboard, Format Painter or return to Conditional Formatting with a CF formatted cell selected, go to Manage Rules... and adjust the *Applies to* range, OK.